# Apply google.maps.LatLngBounds() but not working - Ionic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add google maps in my ionic project. Other than that, I want all the markers in google maps fits all in screen. I don't know where it wrong. My reference here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds

Here is the code

**HTML: index.html**

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script
```

**HTML: home.html**

```
<ion-content>   
   <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
</ion-content>
```

**JS: directives.js**

```js
angular.module('starter.directives', [])

    .directive('map', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
      onCreate: '&'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

        $scope.onCreate({map: map});

        // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
        google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
      }

      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        initialize();
      } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**JS: app.js**

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.directives'])
```

**JS: controllers.js**

```js
$scope.mapCreated = function (map) {
        $scope.map = map;

        var pos = new Array (new google.maps.LatLng(3.050511,101.687833), new google.maps.LatLng(3.122847,101.676846), new google.maps.LatLng(3.078409,101.608025), new google.maps.LatLng(2.932928,101.642603));

        //Create marker
        var createMarker = function (pos, icon) {
            console.log("create marker");
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
            });
        }

        var getAllMarkers = function(){
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for(var i=0; i<pos.length; i++){
                bounds.extend(pos[i]);
                createMarker(pos[i], 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');
            }

            $scope.map.fitBounds (bounds);
        }

        getAllMarkers();
        $scope.map.setCenter(pos[0]);
    };
```

**Output from the code: Picture 1**

[image: Picture 1]

**This is the output that I want: Picture 2**

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: You have a syntax error in this line: `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp</script>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see any errors in my log. I tried again by comment all the code related with google.maps.LatLngBounds(), then the output is okay, nothing errors but it didn't show all the markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use ngMap or other Angular-module (for example angular-google-map).

Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngMap']);

app.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'NgMap', '$timeout', 
function($scope, $http, $state, NgMap, $timeout) {
  
  $scope.zoom = 10;
  
  $scope.cx = {
    "latitude": 3.050511, "longitude": 101.687833
  };
  
  $scope.pos = [{"lat": 3.050511,"lng": 101.687833},
  {"lat": 3.122847,"lng": 101.676846}, 
  {"lat": 3.078409,"lng": 101.608025}, 
  {"lat": 2.932928,"lng": 101.642603}
  ];
  
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
  });

}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>Simle Map</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Simple Map" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="ng-map,AngularJS,center" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Simple Map in Ionic</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        NgMap
      </div>
      <ng-map center="{{cx.latitude}}, {{cx.longitude}}" zoom="{{zoom}}" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <marker ng-repeat="p in pos track by $index" position="{{p.lat}}, {{p.lng}}"></marker>
      </ng-map>
      <pre>cx = {{cx|json}}</pre>
      <pre>pos = {{pos|json}}</pre>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
    Footer
  </ion-footer-bar>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad, it works. I tried to use your code then create a new ionic project. In my new project I'm display my map in two page, first in normal page (<ion-view>) and another page in modal view (<ion-modal-view>). Both of it have different outputs. For normal page output everything goes well but for modal view output the maps is not centered at desired/initialize/$scope.cx coordinate. The view little bit to the right side and only 1 marker can be seen at the left top of maps. The other marker is appeared but we need to move the cursor to show all the markers. Thanks.

Comment: Your question was incomplete...you didn't mentioned modals. However you can check this answer and the Plunker referenced in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386486/ng-map-ionic-running-but-center-is-at-top-left-into-modal/34393146#34393146

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of changes that demonstrates how to notify a controller once the map is created.

**For `directive`:**

```
$scope.$emit('onCreate',map);
```

**For `controller`:**

```
$scope.$on('onCreate', function (event, map) {
     $scope.map = map;
     //the remaining code goes here... 
});
```

[**Demo on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/JGrRgy)

Comment: Thanks, your code worked then I tried to add modal into my project to show map also into it. But it seems like not working. Demo: http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/ZQaYjz?editors=101  ..thanks.